# What's the fastest way to clone a Linux installed computer?

Tags: clone

We have several same branded/model computers and would like to clone Linux-Mint. It takes about 1 hour to install/upgrade etc. for one computer. I used *dd* command to make an image file and saved on external harddisk/usb. Then, I booted the other computer that has no operating system with a live Linux Mint USB and write the image into the harddisk by using *dd* command. It takes about 25 minutes. Then I booted but I saw "no operating system found" message. I couldn't understand what's wrong. Briefly what's the fastest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: We can not tell you **why** it did not work, as you did not show what you did.

Comment: I can't find it right now. However, I read that Penn Manor high school, developed a system to do an install very quickly. They use it in the school, because they have given full control of the devices to the students, but this means that sometimes students break the OS. They needed a way to quickly re-install.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I used to save image: "sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/mint/myexternalhdd/linuximage.img" and to write image: "sudo if=/media/mint/myexternalhdd/linuximage.img of=/dev/sda". To make image size smaller, I made a partition (sda1) before save image file of Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used to save image: "sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/mint/myexternalhdd/linuximage.img" and to write image: "sudo if=/media/mint/myexternalhdd/linuximage.img of=/dev/sda".

You created your image from a partition, but you restored that partition's contents to the whole disk. That not only means that various paths might be incorrect (e.g. in the bootloader configuration) you also didn't bring with you the MBR.

I would suggest you use a higher-level tool such as [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) for this. Or, if you want more control, restore to a partition and make sure to install the bootloader in the MBR (or the EFI system partition).